# Interactive lstBox through LINQ

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering how to create an interactive lstBox that will add/delete characters as I type them into the text box. I copied a text file with 193 results into my lstBox and have a text box above that. The list box is an alphabetical order of all the countries in the UN. I want the text box to narrow my list down as I type and as I delete characters from the textbox cause the lstBox to expand as well. How would I go about doing this?

Is LINQ the correct way to go about this? Not really sure where to start all I have so far is

```
    Public Class nations

Dim nations() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Nations.txt")

Private Sub nations_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lstResults.Items.AddRange(nations)
End Sub

Private Sub txtNation_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNation.TextChanged

    Dim nationQuery = From nation In nations
                      Order By nation.StartsWith("z")
                      Select nation
    lstResults.DataSource = nationQuery.ToList

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sounds like AutoComplete but I have no idea how a listbox plays into it

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a8e2d83c49321790dfa03c954675a8c2 is a screenshot. AutoComplete seems like a different concept. I just want the country to show up based off my search, and have it narrow it down.

Comment: whats wrong with what you have?

Comment: @Devin did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Well you aren't actually filtering the list, just ordering it. Try this

```
Private Sub txtNation_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtNation.TextChanged
    Dim text = txtNation.Text
    Dim nationQuery = From nation In nations
                      Where nation.ToUpper().Contains(text.ToUpper())
                      Order By nation.ToUpper().StartsWith(text.ToUpper()) Descending
                      Select nation
    Me.lstResults.DataSource = nationQuery.ToList()
End Sub
```

Note: I added `ToUpper()` everywhere to ignore case. Also I added the `Where` clause to actually filter the list.